# Authenticate to VSTS using simple console aplication

Tags: .net, rest, authentication, console-application, azure-devops

I need to make simple console app (.NET) which takes all my work items from [VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/). And to do that according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth) article I have to register my app and provide VALID callback url where an access token will be send. Then I can use this token to request the work items from another API. According to this I have to make a web app and host it somewhere because the callback url must be VALID and SECURE. Can you give me a simple way where I can provide user's credentials (get token) and request work items.

Comment: For a console app, just use a Personal Access Token, Alternate Credential or just call EnsureAuthenticated and VSTS will open a pop-up. No need for callbacks and OAuth flows and such, those are for registering a Web Application

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/get-started/rest/basics

Comment: I don't want to use Personal Access Token. I want to provide credentials and receive a token.

Comment: Then just call EnsureAuthenticated.

Comment: Do you solve the issue with my solution?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a console app, you can refer to this code below, it will prompt a Microsoft login window for authentication. (Install [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) package to your project)

```
var u = new Uri("https://XX.visualstudio.com");
var connection = new VssConnection(u, new VssClientCredentials());
var workitemClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
```

Regarding OAuth, it’s better use it in a web app, there is a sample project: [ASP.NET web app (OAuth sample)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-auth-samples/tree/master/OAuthWebSample).

If you still want to use it in a console app, you can try it with Socket to listen to corresponding port for OAuth callback.

Comment: I also have a console app, **not a web app**, that needs OAuth, **not a personal access token**. How do I use OAuth *with Socket to listen to corresponding port for OAuth callback*?